# On reboot yocto system, all files revert to previous versions

Tags: linux, embedded, reboot, yocto

I try to make some changes in my Yocto system but every time I do reboot all the files revert to previous versions. Even when I open a folder after reboot the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you add some more information? Currently no-one will be able to tell you what you're doing...

What system? Which filesystems are being used? (What's your output from running `mount`?). Where are you creating your file and directories? How are you rebooting? I think that might be a good start.

Comment: freescale TWR -LS1021A , kernel version :3.12.0, poky (yocto project...) 1.5, GNU/LINUX  . I try to create folder inside the home folder and I just write reboot in the terminal.

Comment: the output of mount: http://postimg.org/image/wzjejkvz1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in this case, the issue is that @amit-sabag is running his system using initrd/initramfs. This is showns from his [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/wzjejkvz1/). This means that no changes will survive a reboot, as the rootfs is only stored in RAM.

You need to use a rootfs stored on some persistent media, SD-card, NAND-flash, USB-stick, etc...

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot